# how to create a hidden video recorder application with a webcam when click a link?

Tags: php, jquery, video-streaming, video-capture, video-recording

I have a link menu, when I clicked on the menu, then using a webcam video recording applications will automatically run record.
How to make it? do i have to install an app?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML5 feature include now the possibility to use micro and webcam.
You can start here :
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5

Also tutorial here :
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/

Mozilla Camera Api guide
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/Camera

Comment: What you are no references to bypass a permission when recording video? like allow camera etc.

Comment: No, sorry, there is no way you can by-pass user- acceptance for allowing camera.
i mean, there is no "legal" way.